# Link off splash pages

Tags: landing-page

I'm currently working on a project that has a splash page that all new users are directed to ahead of the full website. We're currently debating the behavior of new users when they encounter this splash page and wondering whether linking off to the full site for more details vs. keeping them on the splash will yield a better sign-up conversion.

As the product is new, users will probably want to ascertain a certain amount of information before they decide whether to sign up or not. We do cover off the main points on the splash with a big sign-up CTA.

Question is, are people more likely to sign-up if we give them no option other than vs. providing a clear find out more link in hope that those who are not yet convinced, browse the full site and sign up from there.

Be great to hear your thoughts/experiences and understand if there is any existing research to support either approach?

Answer (score 2):

Provide both, do what you doing with a find out more for those that need it. It shouldn't have to be an either/or solution. In the time that you spend debating you could have tried one approach, checked the conversion rate and then iterate based on your data. You will need to do that anyway with either solution, updating your design for maximum conversion. If you're thinking you're going to come up with the perfectly converting path and design without that you're in for a surprise.